# i want to split row data in database and save to another table in different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

i have data like this  genre =

```
Animation / Family / Fantasy / Musical / Romance
```

i want to save like =

```
Animation
Family
Fantasy
Musical
Romance
```

In Different rows of new table

Answer (score 1):

Splitting a delimited string is painful in MySQL - and often indicates a desing problem. You would be better off storing each value in a separate table.

That said, here is a solution to parse the string using a table of numbers:

```
select substring_index(substring_index (genre, ' / ', x.n), ' / ', -1) genre1
from t
inner join (
    select 1 n 
    union all select 2 
    union all select 3 
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
) x on x.n <= 1 + length(genre) - length(replace(genre, '/', ''))
```

This can parse up to 5 values per string; to handle more, you need to add more `union all` subqueries.

---

In very recent versions, the `values` syntax can be used to shorten the query:

```
select substring_index(substring_index (genre, ' / ', x.n), ' / ', -1) genre1
from t
inner join (values row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5)) x(n) 
    on x.n <= 1 + length(genre) - length(replace(genre, '/', ''))
```

---

Finally - for the fun of it: in MySQL 8.0 this can be done with a recursive query, which is more flexible (although possibly less efficient):

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 
        genre, 
        substring_index(substring_index (genre, ' / ', 1), ' / ', -1) genre1, 
        1 n,
        1 + length(genre) - length(replace(genre, '/', '')) n_max
    from t
    union all
    select 
        genre, 
        substring_index(substring_index (genre, ' / ', n + 1), ' / ', -1),
        n + 1,
        n_max
    from cte
    where n < n_max
)
select genre1 from cte
```

---

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7b3389d227c37a1c5260989917edb14)**:

```
| genre1    |
| :-------- |
| Animation |
| Family    |
| Fantasy   |
| Musical   |
| Romance   |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (genre)
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(genres, '/', 1)) FROM OldTable
 UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(genres, '/', 2), '/', -1)) FROM OldTable
 UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(genres, '/', 3), '/', -1)) FROM OldTable
 UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(genres, '/', 4), '/', -1)) FROM OldTable
 UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(genres, '/', 5), '/', -1)) FROM OldTable;
```

Read more about [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and [TRIM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).